# SSHLibrary - A shell script with arguments exits with code 127 and error 'java: command not found'

Tags: unix, ssh, robotframework

Using Robotframework automation with ssh library, i am trying to execute a shell script with one argument (-a), on a remote UNIX box

The test steps are as follows:

1. Login to the UNIX box
2. Go to the directory where the shell script with argument (-a) is present
3. Execute the shell script

Please note:

1. Since 'SSHLibrary' keywords like 'Execute command' or 'Write' and 'Read' work in a single shell, i am passing multiple commands separated by a semicolon
2. In the series of commands, i also tried turning ON the shell using command `shopt login_shell` but this too did not work. Also note that the command `shopt login_shell` is not turning ON the shell when executed with 'Execute command' keyword. It works fine with 'Write' keyword
3. The following command to check if JAVA is loaded in the automation shell, returns a correct output (path to JAVA).

   Write   $JAVA_HOME
   ${Op_java}= Read

   - Problem:

Following robotframework test step after logging in to the UNIX box fails with exit code 127 and error 'java: command not found'

**Method 1 that I tried:**

```
Write   shopt login_shell
${Op_Shopt}=    Read
${Op_rc}    ${Op_err}=  Execute Command cd /home/xyz/abc; ./shell_script.sh -a  return_stderr=True
```

Here the login_shell is turned ON but somewhere within the shell script the Execute Command keyword exits with code 127 and error 'java: command not found'

**Method 2 that I tried:**

```
Write   shopt login_shell; cd /home/xyz/abc; ./shell_script.sh -a
${Op_shell}=    Read
```

Here the login_shell is NOT turned ON and even here too the Execute Command keyword exits with code 127 and error 'java: command not found'.
As mentioned below, i also tried the same approach with the keyword 'Start Command', but still the same issue.

```
Start Command   shopt login_shell; cd /home/xyz/abc; ./shell_script.sh -a
${Op_rc}    ${Op_err}=  Read Command Output return_stderr=True
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you please provide the testcase you are executing? please use to `code` formatting for better readability. The problem is somewhere in your logic tho.

Comment: SSH library opens new shell (without sourcing any profile file) for every start command or execute command keyword. So try adding "source ~/.bash_profile" or "source ~/.bashrc" into the command, as probably this will set $PATH variable (JAVA_HOME is not that important).